# graph api - is it possible exclude id field?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Is it possible exclude id field with "fields" query parameter, for example:

https://graph.facebook.com/zuck?fields=name

[image]

I'm not asking for FQL, i'm just curious the possibility to exclude id at this point.

Comment: No. That's certainly not possible. Just curious, how does that matter to you?

Comment: If a developer doesn't require the id field, that's means the field is wasting bandwidth. If my query want to include id, i would do fields=id,name. And i think the design is limit the flexibility of API.

Comment: That's your way of looking, but talking of bandwidth just 10 characters dont effect that

Comment: It's not only a matter of bandwith (which, by the way, is more that 10 characters if you're retrieving an edge with dozen of elements), but you may also have to add one line of code to get rid of this unrequired data, one line of comment to explain why, one unit test to prove this works fine... In one word, more complexity to a thing which could have been kept simple.